# Issue using DotNetOpenId with Google Apps

Tags: .net, openid, dotnetopenauth, assertion

I am in a critical situation as we have to integrate Google Apps support to our application, which is in .Net 2.0 framework. So for this I am using DotNetOpenId v2.5.7. Earlier in order to achieve this we created a separate application in framework 4.0 using DotNetOpenAuth v3.4.6 that would do the authentication with Google Apps and redirect the data back with all information. But that process had security loop holes. So now we are bound to use DotNetOpenId as our application cannot be migrated to higher framework.

The main issue is when using it with Google Apps. It works fine for Gmail accounts that has its OpenId Endpoint as *https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud*. However when OpenId Endpoint is something like this *https://www.google.com/a/example.com/o8/ud?be=o8* it gives me an assertion error. The application redirects the user correctly to the Google Apps login page. But when it comes back with data the Authentication Status is Failed and following is the exception in it:

```
Message: The OpenId Provider issued an assertion for an Identifier whose discovery information did not match.

Assertion endpoint info: 
ClaimedIdentifier: http://example.com/openid?id=11......010 
ProviderLocalIdentifier: http://example.com/openid?id=11......010 
ProviderEndpoint: https://www.google.com/a/example.com/o8/ud?be=o8 
OpenID version: 2.0 
Service Type URIs: (unavailable) 

Discovered endpoint info: 
{ClaimedIdentifier: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select 
ProviderLocalIdentifier: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select 
ProviderEndpoint: https://www.google.com/a/example.com/o8/ud?be=o8 
OpenID version: 2.0 
Service Type URIs: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/server, }
```

I have placed an XRDS file which gets download at this location *http://example.com/openid* which has data as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xrds:XRDS xmlns:xrds="xri://$xrds" xmlns="xri://$xrd*($v*2.0)">
    <XRD>
        <Service priority="0">
            <Type>http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/server</Type>
            <URI>https://www.google.com/a/example.com/o8/ud?be=o8</URI>
        </Service>
        <Service priority="10">
            <Type>http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/signon</Type>
            <URI>https://www.google.com/a/example.com/o8/ud?be=o8</URI>
        </Service>
    </XRD>
</xrds:XRDS>
```

But this didn’t help either.

I also placed a file at location *http://example.com/.well-known/host-meta* with this content:

```
Link: <https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=example.com>; rel="describedby http://reltype.google.com/openid/xrd-op"; type="application/xrds+xml"
```

Please tell me what else I need to do. I have been browsing forums and using Google since days to resolve this issue but no progress.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that DotNetOpenId v2.x targets .NET 2.0.  It cannot login users via their Google Apps OpenIDs because Google Apps do not follow the OpenID protocol, but rather Google's own variant of it.

DotNetOpenAuth v3.x is pluggable in a way that allows Google Apps to work by activating support for their variant of OpenID.

I think what will help you most is knowing that DotNetOpenAuth does *not* require .NET 4.0.  Simply install .NET 3.5, which is a low-impact in-place update for .NET 2.0.  Your web sites should continue functioning normally, but DotNetOpenAuth v3.x will work on it.

Comment: Thank you Andrew very much for the quick reply. However we tried by converting our application in .Net framework 3.5 but that leads to issues in our website as we have been using many third party controls of older version that are being used and we do not want to migrate all of them now. So higher framework is not even an option. Please let me know if there is any other possible solution.

Comment: The remaining option is to pay someone to write a custom upgrade to DotNetOpenId v2.x to allow Google interoperability.  (by the way, StackOverflow would prefer you use "add comment" on an existing answer when you are replying to someone's answer, rather than posting your own.)